# Advice for proving with induction scenarios with multiple chances for using the hypothesis.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have done many, many questions about solving induction exercises. I managed to grasp a basic strategy: write all the information, take the statement you want to prove, try to apply the hypothesis somewhere, and then algebra.

Unfortunately, often you will work with a statement with many "options" to apply your hypothesis, and I find it hard to choose the best one.

The following is an exercise I got stuck with, but I'm not really interested in its particular solution. Instead, it presents another of those "multiple-choices" scenarios where you can apply your hypothesis, and I'd like to ask for your feedback on *how should I react when that happens*. Do I pick this, or that, or do something else? Observe:

> Prove by induction that $$12^n+6^{2n}-3^n+120$$ is divisible by 11 for
>   all $n \ge 1$.

---

Test for $n = 1$:

$$12^1+6^2-3^1+120 = 155 = 11 \cdot 15$$

---

We want to prove that it holds for $n+1$, that is:

$$(\exists k \in \mathbb{N})(12^{n+1}+6^{2n+2}-3^{n+1}+120 = 11k)$$

---

Hypothesis:

$$(\exists k \in \mathbb{N})(12^{n}+6^{2n}-3^{n}+120 = 11k)$$

---

We start:

$$12^{n+1}+6^{2n+2}-3^{n+1}+120$$

Here we are proving this. If I expand it a bit I get

$$12^{n}\cdot12+6^{2n}\cdot6^2-3^{n}\cdot3+120$$

Interesting - it seems like there are at least **four** elements to pick from:

$$\color{blue}{12^{n}}\cdot12+\color{red}{6^{2n}}\cdot6^2-\color{magenta}{3^{n}}\cdot3+\color{cyan}{120}$$

In all four cases I could replace them with the hypothesis.

When this happens, I tend to pick the first one without thinking much, and then work with just that. It sometimes leads me to the answer, but more often will it make the whole proof very long and hard.

What kind of mindset should one have, in this kind of situation? I'm not quite interested in "alternative ways to prove this" - I really want to address this scenario. I could keep on trying more exercises and getting help when stuck, but I think it is much more productive to understand my own decision-making issues.

Also note that this kind of issue is not specific to divisibility - it also happens with equalities and inequalities - all in the real of proof by induction of course.

Comment: What choices do you mean? To take either $12^{n+1}+6^{2n+2}-3^{n+1}+120 = (12^n+2^{2n}-3^n+120)\cdot 12+(\ldots)$ or $12^{n+1}+6^{2n+2}-3^{n+1}+120 = (12^n+2^{2n}-3^n+120)\cdot 6^2+(\ldots)$ or ... as next step?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes, to choose which of the four terms to replace as my next step.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if you have several options, the following can happen:

- The first option you try leads to a success. Then there is no need to worry about the other options.
- After trying out several options, one leads to success. Of course it might have saved you time if you had started with the successful option, but how should you know beforehand? So there's littel to be done about this.
- None of the options works. Dammit.

Comment: If you were in my situation, looking at these four options, you'd also pick one by one? Well, I guess that's a relief, kinda lol.

Comment: @Omega Well, actually I might take a completely different approach, such as observing $12\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ and $6^2\equiv 3\pmod {11}$ or ...

Comment: Hm, I'm not very familiar with that, but it sounds interesting - could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You specifically said that you were not quite interested in alternative ways to prove this. The basic observation is that $a\equiv b\pmod m$ implies $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod m$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ (which can be shown by straightforward induction). Hence $12^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, which "cancels" against $120\equiv -1\pmod{11}$, and $6^{2n}=36^n\equiv 3^n\pmod{11}$, which cancels against $3^n$, voila.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I know I asked for this scenario - this was out of curiosity.